# Will I be fingerprinted arriving in the UK? Paris to London Eurostar - Aussie Citizen

Tags: uk, international-travel, australian-citizens, eurostar

I am catching the train from Paris to London.

I want to know if I will be fingerprinted if arriving in the UK as a tourist.

Answer (score 8):

The fingerprinting by UK Immigration on arrival is called "Secure ID". It is used for people travelling on UK Visas or UK Biometric Residence Permits who will have provided their biometrics (fingerprints) when applying for their Visa or Entry Clearance. The machine compares the person's prints to those on file. Only two digits are compared, usually thumb and index finger.If the prints don't match the Officer will ask you to wait while they check your Visa/Entry Clearance application (on-line) to perhaps ask you some verification questions (eg purpose, dates etc). People who do not require Visas visiting the UK as 'Visitors' do not use 'Secure ID' as UK Immigration has not got your fingerprints on file. There is another circumstance too. If you are required to undergo further questioning and are placed in a secure holding room then all your fingerprints will be captured on a separate system along with a photo.

Comment: And to clarify, this would happen in Gare du Nord in Paris before boarding the train.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're somehow distinctive, or have interesting information in the UKVI computer, the answer is "no." You'll pass through UK Immigration in the Gare du Nord, Paris, before you're allowed to board the train.

Comment: Thanks, I remember always being fingerprinted at Heathrow. Why is the train different? is it because i"m coming from a Schengen country?

Comment: @user97176 That's a little strange. How many hours do they usually detain you? Do you know why you are detained?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've always been fingerprinted at Heathrow, even when I had a business visa to the UK. I've never been detained and don't have any criminal record. It might be because I was born in Iran.

Comment: @user97176 Wow, you're the first person I've ever heard of who was _routinely_ fingerprinted while entering the UK. I have only ever heard of people being fingerprinted who were detained for some reason. They never explained to you why they were doing it? Can you tell anything else about this process?

Comment: @user97176 this is getting _really_ interesting, perhaps a question-self answer is in order. I know about fingerprinting during boarding https://findbiometrics.com/biometric-screening-heathrow-404102/ but for immigration purposes, I never heard of any country but the USA doing that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah sure, well, I'm always asked to put my fingerprints on the fingerprint scanning device. I presume that's the "fingerprinting" you're also referring to. They look at my place of birth: Tehran and then ask me to do it. They ask me why I am visiting and whom I am visiting.  I don't have a criminal record and neither am I a person of interest, but I do find the being asked to put my thumb, index finger blah blah blah pretty intrusive. Thus, I do want to catch the train from Paris to London so as to avoid this. You guys saying nobody or most ppl don't get fingerprinted?

Comment: Increasingly, Immigration is done via automated kiosks. *Everyone* who goes through such kiosks places their fingers on a scanner, so in that sense all are fingerprinted. Happens to me too (in both the US and NZ) and I'm a US citizen who wasn't born in Iran.

Comment: @David To clarify, does arriving from Paris to London via Eurostar require me to put my fingers on a scanner?

Comment: @user97176 I don't know; the last time I took Eurostar was in 2009, before automated kiosks. I don't know how they do it now at UK Immigration in Gare du Nord. If they have kiosks there, you might pass right through it, or you might be detoured from the kiosk to a UKVI Immigration Officer.

Comment: As far as I know, the UK currently only uses automated kiosks for UK/EU/EEA/Swiss citizens, and these are based on face recognition rather than fingerprints. Australian citizens will also be able to use these kiosks later this year, but it still won't capture fingerprints, and regardless, there aren't any automated kiosks at Eurostar terminals.

Comment: @chx When that article refers to biometrics, it could only mean facial recognition, since this is the only biometric data which is stored on UK passports. This is similar to the biometric entry kiosks used at UK airports, which also don't use fingerprints.

Comment: Perhaps the clue is that @user97176 said "even when I had a business visa." Entering on a visa is different than entering visa-free. Have you entered without a visa and also been fingerprinted?

Comment: @David The automated UK immigration gates don't take fingerprints and are only used by visitors with EU passports.